# An exploit test: how to test / execute a shellcode?

Tags: c++, exploit, shellcode

Currently I'm learning about vulnerabilities and how to write exploits. And now I'm trying to do an exercise in which I have to take control of EIP (after I make an stack buffer overflow) and execute some shellcode.

The problem is that my shellcode doesn't do anything. So I tried to execute it from a C program to verify if it is working.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>


char shellcode[] = "\x31\xd2\xb2\x30\x64\x8b\x12\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x1c\x8b\x42"
"\x08\x8b\x72\x20\x8b\x12\x80\x7e\x0c\x33\x75\xf2\x89\xc7\x03"
"\x78\x3c\x8b\x57\x78\x01\xc2\x8b\x7a\x20\x01\xc7\x31\xed\x8b"
"\x34\xaf\x01\xc6\x45\x81\x3e\x46\x61\x74\x61\x75\xf2\x81\x7e"
"\x08\x45\x78\x69\x74\x75\xe9\x8b\x7a\x24\x01\xc7\x66\x8b\x2c"
"\x6f\x8b\x7a\x1c\x01\xc7\x8b\x7c\xaf\xfc\x01\xc7\x68\x79\x74"
"\x65\x01\x68\x6b\x65\x6e\x42\x68\x20\x42\x72\x6f\x89\xe1\xfe"
"\x49\x0b\x31\xc0\x51\x50\xff\xd7";


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int(*f)();
    f = (int(*)())shellcode;(int)(*f)();
}
```

But when I execute it, I receive this error:
[C2440 (click here for photo)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS4gm.png)
[image]

> `C2440:'type cast'::cannot convert from 'char[114]' to 'int (_cdecl*)(void)'`

And I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Comment: Try making it a constant.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error into your question, rather than making a screenshot, and linking to it.

Comment: Compiled ok with g++ 5.4.0 and gave a run-time error .. fatal application exit .. in cygwin.

Comment: If I make it constant I receive the same error (C2440).